# Extrair elementos de Dados de 2 API

Tags: angular, typescript

Os dados das duas API's vem no meu console, o problema é que no html no *ngFor só é possível varrer os elementos do 1º subscribe que armazeno em `dados`, gostaria de armazenar os dados das 2 api's de forma a usar os dados na mesma tela, seja no mesmo array ou conseguindo trazer do array que ja criei em `dados2`..

Dados Lista component

```
private dados: Dados[];
private dados2: DadosComp[];

constructor(
  private dadosService: DadosService,
  private http: Http)
  {   }

  getListarDados(){       
    this.dadosService.listarDados()
      .subscribe(
         dados => {this.dados = dados

         for(let i=0; i < this.dados.length; i++){
           let userId = this.dados[i].userId;

           if (userId != null){
               this.dadosService.listarDemaisDados(userId)
               .subscribe(
                   dados2 => {this.dados2 = dados2
                  //mostra todos os dados do 1ºsubcribe
                  console.log(this.dados)
                  //mostra todos os dados do 2ºsubscribe baseado no userId do 1º subscribe
                  console.log(this.dados2)
                   },
                   error => this.msgErro = error             
               );  
           }
           else{userId = 9999;}
        }                        
 },
        error => this.msgErro = error             
            );                                   
    }
```

dados-service.ts

```
// -------------- conexão com 1ª API 
listarDados(): Observable<Dados[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.API_URL, null)
            .map(res => res.json(),
                //this.listarDemaisDados(idUser)
            )
            .catch(this.httpUtil.processarErros);                
}  

// -------------- conexão com 2ª API 
private path: number;
listarDemaisDados(userId: number): Observable<Dados[]>{

    //this.httpUtil.url(this.loginUrl), params, this.httpUtil.headers()
    //console.log(userId);
    this.path = userId;

    let API2_URL: string = 'linkdinamico/' + this.path;

    return this.http.get(API2_URL, this.httpUtil.headers())
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.httpUtil.processarErros);    
}
```

html

```
<tr *ngFor="let dado of dados; ">

        <td>{{ dado.serverDate }} {{ dado.serverTimePrettyFirstAction }}</td>
        <td>{{ dado.totalAbandonedCartsRevenue }}</td>
        <td>{{ dado.totalAbandonedCartsItems }}</td>
        <td>{{ dado.userId  }}</td>


        <!-- ESTES  SÃO OS CAMPOS QUE VEM BASEADOS DA 2ª API (dados2 - do component) e não consigo trazer -->
        <td>{{ dado.dsResponsibleName }}</td>

        <!-- ESTES SÃO OS CAMPOS QUE VEM BASEADOS DA 2ª API (dados2 - do component) e não consigo trazer -->
        <td>{{ dado.dsResponsibleName }}</td>
                <!--{{ dado.nuPhone }}</td -->
        <td>


                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalExcluir"
                    (click)="excluir(aluno.id)">
                    Ações
                </button>
            </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: os dois arrays possuem o mesmo tamanho?

Comment: Não, o primeiro possui 20 itens devido a paginação, ai carrego apenas 20 por página, o segundo array já é conforme o tamanho do objeto, com todos os dados do JSON.

Comment: então isso vai gerar problemas na hora de mostrar os dados do segundo array. O segundo array está sendo populado e o único problema é iterar sobre os seus elementos?

Comment: Isso! Creio que iterando os elementos dos arrays consigo chamar tudo, né?

Comment: consegue, mas precisa existir uma relação entre os dois arrays para você saber, dado um elemento em uma certa posição no primeiro array, qual elemento em qual posição do segundo você quer acessar

Comment: Tem alguma luz de como faço essa ligação da posição do array com os dados que quero? Essa ligação é feita no HTML ou no Component?

Comment: você pode fazer `<tr *ngFor="let dado of dados; let i = index;">`. Em seguida, algo como `dados2[i]`. Não sei se isso resolve, já que você disse que os dois arrays não possuem o mesmo tamanho.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71724/discussion-between-craj-and-mercador).

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei meu erro! Estava perdendo os dados do objeto..

Quando iterava os dados eu alterava o item tb e criava um outro objeto e os dados eram perdidos, então para não perder eu criei outro array

```
private dados: Dados[]; 
private dados2: DadosComp[]; 
private dados3: Array<Dados>=[];
```

Depois coloquei dentro do meu `subscribe` que lista os detalhes (`dados2`) o comando `push` para o array que criei chamado `dados3` para popular com os dados do `detail` que criei com os dados vindos de `dados2`

e por fim no html chamei passando pelo detail, assim:

```
<tr *ngFor="let dado of dados3; let i = index;"> 
<td>{{ dado.serverDate }} {{ dado.serverTimePrettyFirstAction }}</td> 
<td>{{ dado.totalAbandonedCartsRevenue }}</td> 
<td>{{ dado.totalAbandonedCartsItems }}</td> 
<td>{{ dado.userId }}</td> 
<td>{{ dado.detail.dsResponsibleName }}</td> 
<td> ({{ dado.detail.nuPhoneDDD }}) {{ dado.detail.nuPhone }}</td> 
</tr>
```